# Как извлечь данные из DBF файла в массив на C

Tags: c, dbf

Возникла необходимость обрабатывать массив чисел, записанных в DBF файле.

В сети не нашел ответа на самый необходимый вопрос:
Как извлечь из DBF файла содержимое из i-й строки и j-го столбца?

И попутно: как открыть этот известный файл на чтение на C?

Comment: *В сети не нашел ответа* -- [неужели?](https://github.com/search?l=C&q=dbf&type=Repositories) Вот, [например](https://github.com/watmough/DBF/blob/master/dbf.c).

Answer (score 3):

Дополню коммент. Под DBF подразумевается один из форматов баз данных, известный нынче как [dBase](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBF). Он, конечно, немного устарел, но применяется ещё как (особенно в мозгах преподавателей, живущих в прошлом веке).

Но общий смысл такой: для того, чтобы "обрабатывать массив чисел, записанных в DBF файле", нужно разобраться в формате хранения данных в этом самом DBF. В принципе ничего сложного. Но если возникает вопрос уровня

```
как открыть этот известный файл на чтение на C?
```

то подсказать мало чего могу. Разве что научиться основам языка C и общепрограммистской грамотности.

Answer (score 3):

файл открывается функцией

```
   int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);
```

А далее, если не использовать специальных библиотек, то следует смотреть формат файла, например  [здесь](http://softclipper.net/bazy-dbf/format-fajla-dbf.html)

и читать его содержимое. Сначала заголовок, что бы узнать структуру, (примерно так

`struct header
{
     // Database header Information 
    char     version;
    char     yy;             // Last Update 
    char     mm;
    char     dd;
    long     numRecs;
    unsigned short headerLen; // header Length, Indicates start of data 
    unsigned short recordLen;
    char     zero[16];
    char     hasMdxMemo;    // 0x01 for has mdx, in fox 0x02 for has memo 
    char     codePage;
    char     zero2[2];
} header;`
 `if(read(fd, &header, sizeof(header)) <= 0){
            perror("read");
            return 1;
        }`
)

а потом данные

Answer (score 1):

Если Вам действительно нужно обрабатывать файлы формата dBase-III или dBase-IV, то рекомендую обратаить внимание на библиотеку xBase:

> Xbase (formerly known as xdb, also formerly known as xBase) is a
>   collection of specifiations, programs, utilities and a C++ class
>   library for manipulating Xbase type datafiles and indices.
>
> Xbase is useful for accessing data in legacy dBase 3 and 4 database
>   files as well as a general light-weight database engine.  It includes
>   support for DBF (dBase version 3 and 4) data files, NDX and NTX
>   indexes, and DBT (dBase version 3 and 4).  It supports file and record
>   locking under *nix OS's.